# JSTL escapeXml default

Tags: jsp, escaping, jstl

I know to avoid escaping HTML characters in JSTL to use this:

```
<c:out value="${my.value}" escapeXml="false" />
```

I am wondering if there exists a page directive to make escapeXml false by default, so I need not specify it on that particular page.

Comment: Be careful with XSS attack holes when you're redisplaying user-controlled input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The above does *not* escape HTML, since `escapeXml` is set to false. By default, `escapeXml` is true, and the `<c:out>` tag thus escapes the HTML. If you don't want to escape, you could simply use

```
${my.value}
```

and avoid using `<c:out>` completely, since the only purpose of `<c:out>` is to escape HTML.

Comment: Though using `<c:out value="${my.value}" escapeXml="false" />` clearly documents that you *intended* to insert the value without escaping, whereas `${my.value}` might be a mistake where you *forgot* to use `<c:out>`.